# ASP NET Core 1.0 Mvc CodeTemplates Scaffolding for Views and Controllers

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, scaffolding

I am researching the feasibility of using ASP NET Core for one of my projects which relies a lot on generating views based on POCOs. What I have currently in my ASP NET MVC 5.2. project is this CodeTemplates folder which by default overrides the MvcView and MvcController with Action templates with some T4 Templates of my own.

[image: View of the Solution explorer]

Is this supported in ASP .NET Core projects or not? After trying the same structure it did not scaffold using my templates, only the default ones from the installation.

Comment: Support for T4 templates has been back and forth throughout the life of ASP.NET Core - this thread contains an historic discussion of it https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/272. I believe T4 is supported in general, but if you have found that the structure you used is not working I suspect CodeTemplates are not (yet) supported

Comment: Thanks @Sock, I will do some R&D during the weekend and update the question according to the info from the issue you attached, there seem to be some workarounds and other options, but I didn't see anything yet that works the same way the CodeTemplates folder was used to override the MVC Views T4 templates.

Comment: Don't know if you've found this already but this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/08/22/how-to-customize-scaffolding-templates-for-asp-net-vnext/) helped me get this functionallity in place